# Use Model Method from Different Controller - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application has deals and orders. I'm processing the orders manually by clicking a link my my admin area when viewing the deals.

views/access/deals/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Process Orders", process_orders_access_deal_path(deal) %>
```

In my /controllers/access/deals_controller.rb, I have the following method.

```
def process_orders
    @deal = Deal.find(params[:id])
    @orders = @deal.orders.where("state" == ?, "pending")
    @orders.each do |order|
      order.purchase
    end
 end
```

My purchase method is not in my deals model, it's in my orders model because I set it up there before needing to make changes where orders would not be processed immediately.

Purchase method in orders controller.

```
def purchase
  response = Order.gateway.purchase(order_amount, billing_id, options)
end
```

Is it possible to access the purchase method in my order.rb model from my /controllers/access/deals_controller.rb and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried calling it?

Controllers and models aren't linked by some inexplicable magic. You are able to reference any class (i.e. model) from any other class you want (i.e. controller). There is no restriction.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks but I haven't had to do that before therefore I'm not sure how. In my order model I would just call @order.purchase but from my deals controller I'm not sure how to call the method in the Order model.

Comment: @Robert: The method would be available because it's available for instances of your `Order` model. You need to stop thinking that there's a restriction on the models based on what controller you're in. There simply isn't. Just call `order.purchase` exactly like you're doing and it will work.

Answer (score -2):

Before using Rails read something about object-oriented programming and classes in Ruby. Please don't take it personal, but you cannot write a book without understanding of alphabet. I know it from my own experiences.

Comment: I like to learn by doing and then based on real world problems go and read more information about the topic. I do agree that my knowledge of Ruby and OOP is a little lacking so I think this is a good idea. :)